# How do I store XML data into a mysql database? I don't want foreign keys like crazy

Tags: mysql, xml, database, data-structures

If my XML data is very complex, is there a way I can store this in DB?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "regular" way is to store XML in a CLOB (Character Large Object) and MySQL supports CLOB with 4 data types:

- TINYTEXT - A CLOB column with a maximum length of 255 (2**8 - 1) characters.
- TEXT - A CLOB column with a maximum length of 65,535 (2**16 - 1) characters.
- MEDIUMTEXT - A CLOB column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2**24 - 1) characters.
- LONGTEXT - A CLOB column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2**32 - 1) characters.

Using one or the other depends on your needs.

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what you want your database to do with the XML.

- If you just want to store the XML document for later retrieval, just use a blob or text field. Also check the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing).
- If you are trying to dump/import a model, use mysqldump.
- If you are planning to query on XML, you should probably be using a native XML database such as [eXist-db](http://www.exist-db.org/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a database that has a native XML datatype. Postgres will do this, for example. This will make life much easier for you if you are planning to lots of work with XML in your database.