# Optimal Way to Store data in MySQL from .NET

Tags: mysql, xml, database, json, vb.net

I am collecting user input with a .NET application. The data is send to a MySQL Database and stored there. When needed, the data is requested from the .NET app and printed in the GUI. This all works fine and flawless.

Till now i was making a direct DB connection from my local .NET app to the remote DB. As this is not a good idea i want to put a 'request-handler' in between now: a simple .php file which checks the user privileges before the required action.

As i want to cover several flaws with this new implementation, im thinking what would be the best options to achive the following:

1. prevent that the user puts illegal characters inside the DB
2. keep the data-packages as small as possible
3. easily read & write the data-packages to/from the DB

I have to admit that i am new to mysql/php and DBs in general. But my research till now brought me to the keywords **JSON** and **XML**.

Could somebody tell me which of these, is more convienent for me to use? As the package-size is not the most important, more especially the 'illegal-character' prevention should work flawless...
Am i on the right track with using XML? Any suggestion reagarding my issues are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're using .NET why involve PHP? All your checks and data prep can be done in your .NET code.

Comment: as i am concerned, then i would have to hardcode my DB authentication data in the .net application. I dont want the user to be able to manipulate the DB..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prevent that the user puts illegal characters inside the DB
```

I assume you mean SQL Injection here, right?

To give you an idea of what is possible via SQL Injection, then read [MySQL SQL Injection Cheat Sheet](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/mysql-sql-injection-cheat-sheet).

To mitigate the risk of SQL Injection you need to use prepared statements and parameterized queries as described in the accepted answer to [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
keep the data-packages as small as possible
```

JSON will generate smaller messages than XML, but the support for encoding to JSON will be less readily available, if at all.

```
easily read & write the data-packages to/from the DB
```

MySQL has an XML data type. Learn how to use this type by reading the accepted answer of [How do I store XML data into a mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204261/how-do-i-store-xml-data-into-a-mysql-database-i-dont-want-foreign-keys-like-cr).